# parse IOS FBSDKGraphRequest result using Swift4 JSONDecoder

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, swift4

the result of `FBSDKGraphRequest` is of type any and could be casting to `NSDictionary`, but how to convert it to `Data` object to be able to use this `SWIFT4` feature

```
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder.init()
let fbModel = try? jsonDecoder.decode(FBModel.self, from: dataFromResult)
```

i'm try this but the result was nil as code comments

```
    FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email,name,id"]).start{ (connection, results, error) -> Void in
           let dataFromResult = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: results)
           let stringFromData = String.init(data: dataFromResult, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)//return nil
           let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder.init()
           let fbModel = try? jsonDecoder.decode(FBModel.self, from: dataFromResult)//fbModel nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me but i'm not sure if it is the optimal solution

```
let resDataFromDic = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: resDict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
```